# How to interact with bars in matplotlib by events

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, events, mplcursors

I am trying to find solution how to click on bars.
For example, my chart has a five bars.
I click on the second bar and I try to print in the console: "You selected the second bar".
How can I detect elements in the figure by clicking or by any other way?

Answer (score 2):

[mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable) could be an interesting approach.  In the connected function you can show an annotation, but also e.g. update the statusbar or write something in the console.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

prev = None

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(range(9), range(1, 10), align="center")
ax.set(xticks=range(9), xticklabels=[*'ABCDEFGHI'], title="Hover over a bar")

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)

@cursor.connect("add")
def on_add(sel):
    global prev
    x, y, width, height = sel.artist[sel.target.index].get_bbox().bounds
    sel.annotation.set(text=f"{sel.target.index + 1}: {height}",
                       position=(0, 20), anncoords="offset points")
    sel.annotation.xy = (x + width / 2, y + height)
    bar_num = sel.target.index + 1
    postfix = "st" if bar_num == 1 else "nd" if bar_num == 2 else "rd" if bar_num == 3 else "th"
    if bar_num != prev:
        print(f"You hovered over the {bar_num}{postfix} bar.")
    prev = bar_num

plt.show()
```

Comment: JohanC, great thanks for your solution!! 
It works fine.

Comment: If this solves your question, you might consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark, turning it from gray into green.